# Add login page to an existing angular2 application

Tags: java, angular, angular2-routing

I am new to angular2, and we have a basic running application and I need to write a new login page for this application.

I looked at this tutorial and pretty much am able to replicate this same as standalone:
http://4dev.tech/2016/03/login-screen-and-authentication-with-angular2/

but when I looked to integrate with existing application, I see already different home page defined in app.component, should I rename this app.component to a new component and redirect to it from login component.

what would be the best way to integrate this with minimal changes..best practices around this

Comment: Please add errormessages and relevant code snippets (like router config etc.)

Answer (score 3):

you have to create a loging component and  define the the login in route configuration like this
export const routes:RouterConfig = [

```
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '', component: LoginComponent}] //default to login page
```

in login component. i code like

```
 export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  private jwtHelper:JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
  messages:String[] = [];
  localUser = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
  }
  constructor(private _service:LoginService, private _router:Router) {
  }
  login() {
    this._service.login(this.localUser).then((data) => {
        if (data) {
          this._router.navigate(['/companies']);
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        this.messages = error;
      });
  }
  clearfields() {
    this.localUser.username = '';
    this.localUser.password = '';
    this.messages = [];
  }
 ngOnInit():any {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('auth_key') === undefined) {
      console.log("window.localStorage.getItem('auth_key'): " + window.localStorage.getItem('auth_key'));
    }
    else if (window.localStorage.getItem('auth_key') != null &&    !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(window.localStorage.getItem('auth_key'))) {
      this._router.navigate(['/companies']);
    }
  }
```

after login you can navigate to any page abased on your need